# methods like opencurrentdatabase in perl

Tags: perl, ms-access-2013

I am new to perl. I am asked to execute a macro in ms access database using perl. This is the code i used

```
$oAccess = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Access.Application');  
$oAccess ->OpenCurrentDatabase($path);  
$oAccess ->{DoCmd}->RunMacro("DO ALL");
```

Today when i was executing the program i found that only if the access database is open the code works fine else it returns the following error

```
Can't call method "OpenCurrentDatabase" on an undefined value at auto.pl line 30
```

So I was wondering if i could find any other code which would serve the purpose without an open ms access database.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1711/lib/Win32/OLE.pm#EXAMPLES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $MSAccess;
eval {$MSAccess = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Access.Application')};
die "Access not installed" if $@;
unless (defined $MSAccess) {
  $MSAccess = Win32::OLE->new('Access.Application','Quit')
    or die "Unable to start Access";
}
$MSAccess->{visible} = 0;
```

Comment: i guess this will forcefully open access, but i want the program to execute without opening access(i.e just a driver which would execute the macro).

Comment: @Programmer if you mean you don't want Access to be visable that's doable, otherwise your request doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: yes i dont want access to be visible as we do for `$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:driver=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);dbq=xyz.mdb", $username, $password) || die "Error connecting: $!";`

Comment: Programmer, you need to undertand how Win32::OLE works. It's not the same as using DBI. Macros are run from the client. You're automating the Access client via the Win32::OLE interface. I've updated the example to hide the window. Learn to read the docs for the modules you are working with